# state machines and multiple states

Tags: computer-science

Using the traditional definition of state machines, can state machine records be in multiple states at the same time? For example, if I have a `User` model, can users be in both a `subscriber` and in a `promotional_period` state at the same time?

Note, I am not asking if it makes sense to do this, my question is - is it possible with state machines.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

All the answers saying "no" are only correct if you are assuming the "typical" type of [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (FSMs) known as [deterministic finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFAs), which can only have a single active state at any given time.

However, this is not the only type of FSMs, and there is no good reason to restrict yourself to this type of mechanism in all cases. There are also [nondeterministic finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) (NFAs), which can be in any number of states simultaneously.

This isn't just academic, or even really about parsing (as the wikipedia links might imply): NFAs are actually quite simple and incredibly useful and are used in practice all over the place in both hardware and software implementations.

Basically, to design an NFA, you do it just like a DFA, but instead of having a "current state" and using the inputs to compute a "next state", you have a "current state set" and use the inputs to compute a "next state set". In hardware (e.g. FPGAs implemented in VHDL) this can be done literally simultaneously. In (single-threaded) software, this is typically done by just iterating through the current states in each "step" of the machine.

Comment: Although it isn't the "traditional definition of state machines" I actually consider this a better answer. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be more practical way to handle the scenario in question. I would suggest to make this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

No. State machines have *one* state at a time.

A combination state could be done with another state, like `subscriber_and_promotional_period`. This is the usual way to do it.

Comment: While this is the case with many FSM implementations, this it isn't the whole story, as it is neglects the entire field of non-deterministic finite automata. See my answer for more details.

Comment: But aren't multi-state FSMs equivalent to one-state FSMs?

Answer (score 3):

Quoth the Wikipedia for one day more:

"A finite-state machine (FSM) or finite-state automaton (plural: automata), or simply a state machine, is a mathematical model of computation used to design both computer programs and sequential logic circuits. It is conceived as an abstract machine that can be in one of a finite number of states. **The machine is in only one state at a time; the state it is in at any given time is called the current state.**"

So, no.

Comment: This is a common case of FSM implementations, but it isn't the whole story, though. From the same wikipedia article: "A further distinction is between deterministic (DFA) and non-deterministic (NFA, GNFA) automata. In deterministic automata, every state has exactly one transition for each possible input. In non-deterministic automata, an input can lead to one, more than one or no transition for a given state."

Answer (score 1):

[Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) are a generalization of state machines that allow multiple simultaneous 'states'.